# Serilog SelfLog to File Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, serilog

I need to enable self log of seri logger to text file. My configuration are follows;

```
__serilogLogger = new LoggerConfiguration()
      .Enrich.WithProperty("ApplicationIPv4", _ipv4)
      .Enrich.WithProperty("ApplicationIPv6", _ipv6)
      .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(connectionString, tableName /*, columnOptions: columnOptions*/)
      .WriteTo
      .Seq(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SerilogServer"])
      .CreateLogger();

      var file = File.CreateText("Self.log");
      Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(TextWriter.Synchronized(file));
```

But is hows File access error when run the application. Please find the error details below;

> Additional information: The process cannot access the file 'C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\IIS Express\Self.log' because it is being used by another
>   process.

Can anyone help me on this

Comment: Can you show the code and the line that is raising the error?

Comment: We had similar issue with .NET app using serilog self log under IIS.  Turns out the number of worker processes was set to 8 instead of 1 :(

Comment: It can be tricky to implement self logging via file stream in a safe thread safe manner that works in all scenarios. For .NET core apps,  avoid the headache and make SelfLog target Console.Error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have another instance of this application running when it comes to this line. Or maybe this code is somehow being invoked twice? Check taskmanager and kill anything that maybe using it. If this is a web app try recycling the app pool.

Comment: thanks... yea that is my issue...Code look like logger initializing in multiple places

Answer (score 11):

try

`Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(msg => File.AppendAllText (serilogSelfLogFilePath, msg));`

for a non-locking way to write to a file. `serilogSelfLogFilePath` is a valid path `string` to the file you want to use.

Don't forget `Log.CloseAndFlush();` when you're closing your other logs per https://github.com/serilog/serilog/issues/864 or it won't get written anyway

Note, if you are using an async Sink then you will eventually get an exception when different threads contend to write to that file if it gets busy.

Comment: Any solution for the async Sink case?

Comment: Retry and/or fail or perhaps try a static writer. It’s an edge-case but you need to be aware of it to avoid crashes.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing a problem manifesting this same `The process cannot access the file 'X' because it is being used by another process.` error message. In my case it appeared in the server's event log every time the application pool recycled in IIS 8.5, even though `Maximum worker processes` was set to `1`. Maybe worth saying: the code enabling self log executes in a static constructor.

No luck did I have after properly closing the `TextWriter`, not even when adding generous `Thread.Sleep` before `File.CreateText` in hope of waiting for that "another process" to finish.

The solution was to set `Disable Overlapped Recycle` to `true` in Advanced Settings for the application pool.

[image]