# Why do I get Serilog SelfLog error while using Serilog logging?

Tags: c#, serilog, ioexception, .net-framework-version, serilog-sinks-file

I have an interesting error while using **Serilog SelfLog**. The error is:

```
Application: XXX.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.IOException
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32, System.String)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(System.String, System.IO.FileMode, System.IO.FileAccess, Int32, Boolean, System.IO.FileShare, Int32, System.IO.FileOptions, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, System.String, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(System.String, System.IO.FileMode, System.IO.FileAccess, System.IO.FileShare, Int32, System.IO.FileOptions, System.String, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.CreateFile(System.String, Boolean, Boolean)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(System.String, Boolean, System.Text.Encoding, Int32, Boolean)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(System.String, Boolean, System.Text.Encoding)
   at System.IO.File.InternalAppendAllText(System.String, System.String, System.Text.Encoding)
   at Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.WriteLine(System.String, System.Object, System.Object, System.Object)
   at Serilog.Sinks.PeriodicBatching.PeriodicBatchingSink+<OnTick>d__16.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at Serilog.Sinks.PeriodicBatching.PortableTimer+<OnTick>d__8.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
```

I do not have an idea what happens. I have **.Net framework 4.6.1**, Serilog version 2.9.0 and I cannot produce the error again.

Please Can you help me to describe the error? Why did I get the error? Do you know any solutions for this error?

I use libraries below:

- Serilog v2.9.0
- Serilog.Enrichers.Context v2.4.0
- Serilog.Extensions.Logging v2.0.4
- Serilog.Settings.AppSettings v2.2.2
- Serilog.Sinks.Console v3.1.1
- Serilog.Sinks.File v4.1.0
- Serilog.Sinks.Http v5.2.1
- Serilog.Sinks.PeriodicBatching v2.2.0
- Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile v3.3.0
- Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions v1.0.0

**EDIT:**
My app conf here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="serilog:minimum-level" value="Verbose" />
    <add key="serilog:using:Console" value="Serilog.Sinks.Console" />
    <add key="serilog:write-to:Console" />
    <add key="serilog:using:Http" value="Serilog.Sinks.Http" />
    <add key="serilog:write-to:Http.requestUri" value="http://log.XXX.com:8080/TestEngine" />
    <add key="serilog:write-to:Http.batchPostingLimit" value="1" />
    <add key="serilog:write-to:Http.batchFormatter" value="Serilog.Sinks.Http.BatchFormatters.ArrayBatchFormatter, Serilog.Sinks.Http" />
    <add key="serilog:enrich:with-property:application" value="TestEngine" />
  </appSettings>
    <startup> 
    ...
```

Serilog integration here:

```
var config = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .Enrich.WithMachineName()
    .Enrich.WithUserName()
    .ReadFrom.AppSettings();

if (CustomLogContext == null)
{
   CustomLogContext = new Dictionary<string, object>();
}

foreach (var logContext in CustomLogContext)
{
   config.Enrich.WithProperty(logContext.Key, logContext.Value);
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(CustomLogFileFullName))
{
   config = config.WriteTo.File($"{CustomLogFileFullName}");
}

Serilog.Log.Logger = config.CreateLogger();

Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(msg => File.AppendAllText("internallog.log", msg, Encoding.UTF8));

ILoggerProvider loggerProvider = new SerilogLoggerProvider(Serilog.Log.Logger);

_logger = loggerProvider.CreateLogger("XXX.Logging.Serilog");
```

**SOLUTION:**
As @RubenBartelink says, if you use Selflog but you use custom log files, you take a few risks. Because Serilog may not write a custom file and may be Serilog throw an IO exception. This problem does not belong to Serilog. The problem is actually File.AppendAlltext operation. The solution is as follows:

```
Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(msg => 
{
    try
    {
        File.AppendAllText("internallog.log", msg, Encoding.UTF8);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
});
```

Comment: can you share your configuration? it looks like you have serilog trying to write to a file

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48162875/serilog-selflog-to-file-error https://github.com/serilog/serilog/issues/1272

Comment: that link (https://github.com/serilog/serilog/issues/1272) helped me thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As alluded to in the comment from @Daniel A. White, you are doing a risky thing -- trying to write to a file, in a handler that's provided on an "if all else fails" basis. Some examples:

- if the disk is full and the File Logger can't write (File sinks dont necessarily do that, but if they wanted to communicate failure, it would be via the `SelfLog`)
- if a message string is malformed (Serilog logging calls will never throw; this is based on a fundamental tenet in the wiki about the logging not being important enough to stop a working app from working)

While the [Serilog debugging and diagnostics Wiki page](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Debugging-and-Diagnostics) currently shows an example of writing to a file, that's simply not the nature of the contract -- it must not fail.

Hence, if you actually want to emit the `SelfLog` to a file, you will need to add a `try`/`catch` and swallow the exception in the handler.

I would say its pretty questionable value to have a file as a backup when the File Sink is your primary output. This is doubly the case as you don't have any mechanism to ensure it gets trimmed (imagine you had a tight loop logging with a malformed message string - it would fill your disk eventually).

I personally have handled this tradeoff by echoing the `SelfLog` to my `Console` Sink (which logging won't throw, per the above) on the basis that the operating environment (think Kubernetes) can be trusted to capture it, or alert.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is very clear. There can be a point of misunderstanding for me. Why did the throwing exception of 'selflog' shut down the console app? How?

Comment: The work reporting the error to the SelfLog (the PeriodicBatchingSink bit in the trace) is running as an async continuation and/or timer activity via the `ThreadPool` (see trace). Uncaught exceptions there are reported/handleable via [`AppDomain.UnhandledException`] (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.unhandledexception?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0). Depending on the app type and .NET version, there can be default behaviors and/or an ability to control those (e.g. WinForms has a SetUnhandledExceptionMode). Bottom line is still if you are a failsafe you can't fail.

Comment: Thank you for your explanations, I selected this answer as the solution. And I edited my post to add the solution part.

Comment: Great, and thanks for a good question and follow-ups; hopefully this will help someone else in the future too - the `SelfLog` Wiki article's example does not mention this explicitly but will likely be revised at some point.

Comment: I hope this situation will be added to the wiki in the future. Have a good day :)

Comment: Not 100% unrelated - https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2022/02/20/diagnosing-an-asp-net-core-hard-crash/